# I have 2 ftp servers running

Tags: server, ftp

I have installed VSFTPD but when i turn it off, I can still access my ftp user how can i find the other FTPd and remove it

-Viktor Strate

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you please share how you turn vsftpd off and what `sudo lsof -i` gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at who is listening to the FTP port.

```
$ grep ftp /etc/services
ftp-data    20/tcp
ftp     21/tcp
...<snip>...
# netstat lists all open ports, first egrep picks out servers, second picks ftp servers
$ sudo netstat -nape --inet | egrep '0\.0\.0\.0:\*' | egrep -w '20|21'
```